Import module error while running 'pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=app tests/'
I'm new to pytest, and I'm trying to get my unit tests to run. Right now I'm getting import module errors. I have my project organized in the following:
/project
   /app 
       /core
           __init__.py 
           file1.py      --> "from core.file2 import file2"
           file2.py 
       /routes
       /tests 
           test_file1.py --> "from app.core.file1 import file1"
           test_file2.py --> "from app.core.file2 import file2" 

I'm having trouble understanding where my tests files should be, where should I run 'pytest' and how imports work.
When I run pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=app tests/ in /project/app/, I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' from my test files. When I move the test directory to outside the /app directory and run the same command, I get the same error.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
